# how to change the variable value in Javascript after every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, settimeout

i have an array like

```
  var A=["2","4","5"];
```

I have a set of value in one array. But i need show value only by one between 30 seconds. Can anyone help me.

Comment: I'm so confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Which value you want to change after session timeout ?

Comment: i want the  array value one by one,, first 30seconds  'var A=2' after 30seconds i want 'var A=4',after that 'var A=5'.....

Comment: Not sure how sessions are involved in the question, but in JS you can use [Window timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers).

Comment: @Abdul khader Please include the code for your setTimeout() method and include more details in your question about accessing the values in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method.

```js
(function() {
  var source = ["2", "4", "5"];

  var delay = 1000; // use 30000 for 30 seconds

  var currentIndex = 0;

  var A = source[currentIndex]; // Starting value

  window.console.log(A); // demo

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    currentIndex += 1;
    A = source[currentIndex];

    window.console.log(A); // demo

    // Clear interval 
    if (source.length === currentIndex + 1) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, delay);

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

get each value of items in callback after 30 seconds

```js
function getValue(items, cb, i) {
  i = i || 0;
  if (i < items.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      cb(items[i])
      i++;
      getValue(items, cb, i);
    }, 30 * 1000);
  }
}

getValue(['1', 2, 3], function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```